# Null values not getting replaced using with column condition in PySpark

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have written a PySpark code to put in the condition that if null values are present in a given Column then it append 'Yes' to another column otherwise 'No'

```
data = data.withColumn('Coupon_code',when((data.coupon ==""),"No coupon").otherwise("coupon"))
```

Here condition is on column 'coupon' that if there is null values in 'coupon' column then it it appends "No coupon" in in Coupon_code column otherwise with "coupon"

The problem with above logic is it is not detecting null values and populating every entry with "Coupon"

I tried using is `isnull()` and `subset` but to no avail

data = data.withColumn('Coupon_code',when(data.fillna("No coupon", subset["coupon"])).otherwise("coupon"))

for is null() I am getting error that `column is not callable`. Please suggest where I am going wrong.

Sample data:

I/P:

```
Coupon
null
null
null
null
H45X
E4R
null
```

Expected o/p:

```
Coupon  Coupon_code
null     No Coupon
null     No Coupon
null     No Coupon
null     No Coupon
H45X     coupon
E4R      coupon
null     No Coupon
```

Even count works but same is not able to replicate in replacing it.

```
data.where(col("coupon").isNull()).count()

output: 9064
```

Comment: please post sample data

Comment: Are you sure that the missing value is an empty string ("") and not, for example, whitespace (" ")?

Comment: @LiamGalbraith yes those are empty strings. all are null/none datatypes

Comment: dtype for 'coupon' column is string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try if the code below works for you? It should catch both cases where the column coupon is null or it is an empty string.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

data = data.withColumn('Coupon_code',
    F.when(
        F.col('coupon').isNull() | (F.col('coupon') == F.lit('')),
        "No coupon"
    ).otherwise("coupon")
)
```

Comment: yes now I can see No-coupons part also populating. Any idea why isnull() not working over df.col.isnull() it gives error columns is not a callable function

Comment: it should be isNull, not isnull.